# Swiping app crashes before opening using view pager - Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is my first app using fragments and page swiping. I am trying to create three layouts with buttons and edit texts. The user will be able to swipe between pages. There should be no tabs. The problem is when I upload the app to my phone, it crashes. I went through some tutorials and applied same thing except that they didn't add buttons or edit texts. In the below code, I only included the first fragment because all other fragments are similar.

Main Activity Java:

```
package com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2;
import com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2.TabsPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Top Rated", "Games", "Movies" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
       mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
       actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);


       // Adding Tabs
       /*for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }*/

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                //actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

}
```

Android Manifist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2" >
   <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

First Fragment:

```
package com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

/**
 * Created by IBM on 07-Apr-15.
 */
public class MainPage extends Fragment {
    Button start1,start2,start3;
    Button play1,play2,play3;
    Button stop1,stop2,stop3;
    Button tour;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_page, container, false);
        start1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Start1Button);
        start2 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Start2Button);
        start3 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Start3Button);
        play1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Video1Button);
        play2 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Video2Button);
        play3 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Video3Button);
        stop1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Stop1Button);
        stop2 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Stop2Button);
        stop3 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Stop3Button);
        tour = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.TourButton);
        return rootView;
    }
    public class ControllerFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    }
}
```

First Fragment XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Welcome"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text ="Tour"
        android:id="@+id/TourButton"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:textSize="30dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text ="Exercise 1"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.16">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/Video1Button"
        android:text= "Play"
        android:layout_weight ="1"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/Start1Button"
            android:text= "Start"
            android:layout_weight ="1"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/Stop1Button"
            android:text= "Stop"
            android:layout_weight ="1"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Exercise 2"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.19">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/Video2Button"
            android:text= "Play"
            android:layout_weight ="1"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/Start2Button"
            android:text= "Start"
            android:layout_weight ="1"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/Stop2Button"
            android:text= "Stop"
            android:layout_weight ="1"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Exercise 3"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.17">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/Video3Button"
            android:text= "Play"
            android:layout_weight ="1"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/Start3Button"
            android:text= "Start"
            android:layout_weight ="1"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/Stop3Button"
            android:text= "Stop"
            android:layout_weight ="1"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Tab Page Adapter:

```
package com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:

            return new ExtraExercise();
        case 1:

            return new MainPage();
        case 2:

            return new OnYourOwn();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 3;
    }

}
```

Log Cat:

```
04-07 18:56:09.588  29377-29377/com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2 I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 29377 SIG: 9
04-07 18:57:44.871  30095-30095/com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2 I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file.
04-07 18:57:44.901  30095-30095/com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2 I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority , spota verifySig and checkHash pass. priority version is VE=SEPF_GT-I9505_4.4.2_0040
04-07 18:57:44.901  30095-30095/com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2 I/SELinux﹕ selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /data/security/spota/seapp_contexts
04-07 18:57:44.901  30095-30095/com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2 E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> Normal User
04-07 18:57:44.901  30095-30095/com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2 E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2 [ userId:0 | appId:10253 ]
04-07 18:57:44.901  30095-30095/com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2 D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
04-07 18:57:45.001  30095-30095/com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2 W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
04-07 18:57:45.011  30095-30095/com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2 I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
04-07 18:57:45.051  30095-30095/com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2 D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-07 18:57:45.051  30095-30095/com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2 W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418c1da0)
04-07 18:57:45.051  30095-30095/com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2, PID: 30095
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2/com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-07 18:57:46.522  30095-30095/com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2 I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 30095 SIG: 9
04-07 19:34:52.119      356-356/com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2 D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-07 19:34:52.119      356-356/com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2 W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418c1da0)
04-07 19:34:52.119      356-356/com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2, PID: 356
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2/com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-07 19:42:48.253    1897-1897/com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2 W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
04-07 19:42:48.253    1897-1897/com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2 I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
04-07 19:42:48.303    1897-1897/com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2 D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-07 19:42:48.303    1897-1897/com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2 W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418c1da0)
04-07 19:42:48.303    1897-1897/com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2, PID: 1897
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2/com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.ibm.exoskeleton_2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: The crash appears to be on line 34 of your MainActivity.java in onCreate. Could you post that file?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to add it :D

Comment: It looks like your ActionBar is being returned as null from `getActionBar()`. As you're using the support FragmentActivity, you could use `getSupportActionBar()` which might solve the issue. Does your AppTheme specify that there is an action bar?

Comment: I tried to use getSupportActionBar. I added a function but it gave me error.  public ActionBar getSupportActionBar() {
        return supportActionBar; // Error
    }

Comment: If you replace your `extends FragmentActivity` with `extends ActionBarActivity` then I believe it should work. I thought the method was in FragmentActivity

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!!!! You are a life savior. I'd like to ask: Why your solution worked? Also, When I open the app I want to a certain layout to be in the first thing to appear. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: Because you're using the support Activities I believe they are using the supportActionBar rather than the normal ActionBar. By using the getSupportActionBar() method you get the correct ActionBar from the support library for backwards compatibility. If you want a certain layout to be displayed, you can either use the `setContentView(R.layout.my_layout)` method and provide a layout, or attach a fragment which loads a layout

Comment: Can u please tell me how to set the layout?  I tried what u said but I get errors :( just tell me where to add the method and what to put inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you replace the `FragmentActivity` with `ActionBarActivity` and use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()` that should solve the problem.